# Appending document in response function

Tags: google-chrome-extension, message-passing

Not sure why, but I'm getting an unexpected identifier error when trying to append an element to the document in a response function. I've found that doing anything with the document seems to give me this error. Here's a sample code:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({send:data},function(response) {
    document.body.innerHTML='test'
    })
```

It looks to me like it should work, but evidently it does now. This piece of code is located in the contentscript, and messing with the document outside of this function seems to work just fine, but I always get "unexpected identifier" when trying this. Unfortunately I cannot do it outside of the function because the response determines whether or not an element is added to the body.

Comment: Works for me (Chrome 12, Win), the problem must be somewhere else. Can you show your background page?

Comment: I restarted Chrome in case there was an update (although I don't believe there was), and oddly enough it worked. Maybe it wasn't updating when I clicked reload and I was getting a prior error. I feel dumb for not trying this before I asked.

Comment: You should post what you did to fix it as an answer and mark it as correct or close the question.

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared should work. Try restarting your browser to see if that fixes it.